# Why this is a good candidate to reopen?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, vote-to-reopen

I have failed this [vote to reopen audit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365346/implement-view-like-view-pager) today, I fail to understand why this should have been reopened? It does not have any code attempts, nor shows any effort (unless that drawing counts as such). I apologise for being a moron and someone to have to spell it out to me, but please explain to me why this should have been re-opened?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Audits are picked automatically. That post has never been closed, and received 9 upvotes and no downvotes, so it was deemed a good candidate by the system.

If you disagree (and well you might), then downvote or vote to close that question.

It gained the +9 because it had a bounty posted on it, so the post score may be somewhat inflated compared to its actual worth; the 'sexy' drawing attracted positive reactions, I'd say. At the very least, that post is begging to be edited for grammar, spelling and clarity.

1 such failed audit is not going to affect your ability to continue to review, in any case.

Comment: I didn't realise that they were picked automatically that explains it. Thanks.

Comment: Sexy is exactly how I'd describe that drawing